# How do you toggle between Dimens/Strings id vs their actual value?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, intellij-idea

This question is kind of difficult to put in words, but I want to know how to toggle between the dimens/strings id's vs their actual values. The IDE is IntelliJ. An image should make it a bit more clear what I'm asking:

[image: Upper image is actual values, lower image is with full id]

Upper image is actual values, lower image is with full id displayed. If you click on the `60dp`, it will then display the full id. I'm interested in how to then revert it back to the original `60dp`. I've spent some time trying to find it online and but couldn't find anything. I know that I could always just do a "go to declaration" on the id and find the actual value in strings.xml, but it would be significantly faster to just read it on the spot. Any other useful IntelliJ/Android tips someone could think of would be welcome too. If you could help me I'd be very happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> to both expand and collapse when the cursor is within the value/code you want to perform `Folding` on or just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>.

This is called code folding and can also be found under the contextual menu (when you right click on the code) then `Folding` (See image below)

[image]

Comment: Thanks that's a pretty cool trick, I knew you could click on the left to collapse/expand, but didn't know it had a shortcut. However when I press `Ctrl + >`, it collapses the entire widget rather than toggling dimens/strings values. Still a useful shortcut to know.

Comment: You should have your cursor at `...="@dimen/<somewhere here>_margin_xx`, get it? The folding can collapse an entire `Class` or just a `Method` in java code depending on where the cusor is positioned.

Comment: Perhaps we have different settings in intelliJ, but regardless of where my cursor is, when I type `Ctrl + >`, it just collapses the entire widget rather than toggle the id with the actual value. I'm interested in toggling the `60dp` and the `@id/....` so that I can see it quickly rather than having to use "go to declaration"

Comment: Not on the id. Dimens and Strings. If it's on the id, it'll collapse the widget. Should i upload a photo or two?

Comment: I meant to type `@dimens/...`, my mistake. I you can upload an image if you like

Comment: Unfortunately this is still not working for me, pressing `Ctrl + >` in the position you are indicating (or any other position for that matter) results in the entire widget collapsing. I think that we may have different settings or something on intelliJ. Does this work or not work for others reading this?

Comment: on ubuntu it's `Ctrl` + `.`

Comment: I just tested this on a coworkers computer and it definitely works. Not sure what is wrong with my IntelliJ, but Elvis's answer is correct